# VBA create If statement to check hours

Tags: vba, if-statement

How do i create a function which takes an amount of hours as argument. Something like this,

```
Function BREAK_TIME(work_time)
    If 4 <= work_time < 9.5 Then
        BREAK_TIME = 30
    End If
    If work_time >= 9.5 Then
        BREAK_TIME = 60
    End If
End Function
```

but how can I tell that it is a time? What I would like it to do is: take an amount of hours, e.g. `07:40:00`, and tell me how many minutes of break the employee have, here 30 minutes.

I apologize the incredible ugly code. First time using VBA and it is not easy to work (any code improvements is also appreciated:) ).

Comment: What exactly are you passing to `work_time`?  A decimal, a datetime, something else?  Why not just pass the hours and minutes in decimal; i.e. instead of `07:40:00`, pass in `7.67` hours.

Comment: When I format the cell to show 24 hours, it is in the format hh:mm:ss. I have a time_to_meet in one cell and a time_you_are_off, then calculate the total_time which is in the aforementioned format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a Date object, which has functionality for storing the various units of time, or you can pass the number of hours either as a floating point number (in your example, 7.666666) or as a set of hours, minutes, and seconds.

I've modified your function:

```
Function BREAK_TIME(work_time as Single) as Single
    If work_time < 4 Then
        BREAK_TIME = 0
    ElseIf work_time >= 4 And work_time < 9.5 Then
        BREAK_TIME = .5
    ElseIf work_time >= 9.5 Then
        BREAK_TIME = 1
    End If
End Function
```

It uses floating point values to represent hours, and returns a value in hours instead of minutes.

Comment: It returns 0 every time? I can pass a set in the format hh:mm:ss?? But works with floating point numbers

Comment: Yes, as it says it does.  If you need to be able to pass a time in "HH:MM:SS" format you'll have to adapt it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to just feed in the start and end times.

```
Function BREAK_TIME(time_to_meet, time_you_are_off)
    'Difference in minutes
    worked = DateDiff("n", time_to_meet, time_you_are_off)

    Select Case worked
    Case Is <= 240
        BREAK_TIME = 0
    Case Is < 570
        BREAK_TIME = 30
    Case Is >= 570
        BREAK_TIME = 60
    End Select
End Function
```

Input could be : `BREAK_TIME #7:40:00 AM#, #2:30:00 PM#`